# Loop isn't scraping multiple pages, only returning data from one page repeatedly

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web, lxml

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

questionlist = []

url = "https://seekingalpha.com/market-news?page=20"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

questions = soup.find_all('article', {'class': 'mT-jA ga-jA Q-b8 R-cS R-df ks-IX R-cG R-dJ ks-IX R-cG R-dJ ks-I0 ks-I0 mT-NM'})

for page in range(1, 10):
    for item in questions:
        question = {
        'title': item.find('h3', {'class': 'km-X R-cw Q-cs km-IM V-gT V-g9 V-hj km-IO V-hY V-ib V-ip km-II R-fZ'}).text,
        'link': 'https://seekingalpha.com/market-news' + item.find('a', {'class': 'hq-ox R-fu'})['href'],
        'date': item.find('span', {'class': 'mU-uO mU-gE'}),
        }
        questionlist.append(question)
    
print(questionlist)
```

Why is my loop not working? I am scraping for multiple pages but the output is coming for a single page multiple times.

Comment: You're only calling `requests.get()` once.  There is no other code that would ever fetch more pages.  How did you expect the code would fetch more pages?

Answer (score 0):

The pagination is implemented with request to external URL via JavaScript (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see the new pages). To simulate this request you can do for example:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/news"

params = {
    "filter[category]": "market-news::all",
    "filter[since]": "0",
    "filter[until]": "0",
    "include": "author,primaryTickers,secondaryTickers",
    "isMounting": "true",
    "page[size]": 25,
    "page[number]": 22,
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0",
    'Referer': 'https://seekingalpha.com/market-news?page=22'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    # set cookies
    s.get('https://seekingalpha.com/market-news')

    for p in range(1, 5):  # <-- increase this range for more pages
        params['page[number]'] = p

        data = s.get(api_url, params=params).json()
        # print sample data
        for d in data["data"]:
            print(d["attributes"]["title"])
```

Prints:

```
...

Thermo Fisher tests for preeclampsia risk gets FDA nod
QCR Holdings declares $0.06 dividend
RingCentral repurchases ~$461M senior notes
Amphenol slips as Credit Suisse downgrades on 'weakness' in certain markets
Innovid receives NYSE notice on non-compliance
Investors were net buyers of fund assets for the fourth consecutive week, adding $4.6B
4 stocks to watch on Friday: Deere, Applied Materials and more
TIO, PHIO and ALIM among pre-market losers

...
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, you need to have a way to tell your loop to actually scrape different web pages. For example having all the links in a list, or updating the link each time when the update is a simple page number change, or telling your code to press a button to change page.

I recommend you to go through following link to learn more. Specifically part titled
**How to Scrape Multiple Web Pages**
[Web Scraping tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-multiple-web-pages-using-python/)